# CSRF Token refresh in different browsers

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, django-csrf, wagtail

I am almost new to django and web development at all, so faced a problem with csrf tokens

Prerequisites: wagtail-based web-site and django rest api on different domains

On website I have a login form (which includes `{% csrf_token %}`).

The js script on submit:

```
function getToken(){
        document.cookie = "path=/; csrftoken = {% csrf_token %}";
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', url, false);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", $.cookie('csrftoken'));
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify({"username":document.getElementById("login").value,
                        "password":document.getElementById("password").value}));
        if (xhr.status != 200) {
            alert( "ERR" );
                    }
        else {
            alert( xhr.responseText );
            document.cookie = "token = " + JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).key;
                }
        }
```

In chrome everyting works fine, but in IE and Opera after a successful login they show me

```
403: CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
```

After I refresh page in IE and Opera everyting is fine, I see my logged in user.

Also I noticed: before and after login csrf token is the same, and in other browsers it changes.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: It's not clear to me, are you trying to submit information from a form on one domain to another domain?

Comment: Assuming you are, take a look at the CORS section here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/